# Rhino and Jasmine and defineClass

Tags: rhino, jasmine

I have some javascript code that uses functions defined in Java with Rhino.

I'm trying to test it in the jasmine-maven-plugin. I'm rather flummoxed by how to get the defineClass to happen.

defineClass is part of the shell in Rhino. It's not added to the language. So I can't just write a defineClass into an ordinary js file.

I can't think of any way to get the jasmine-maven-plugin to invoke some java code of mine to call `ScriptableObject.defineClass`.

I'm about to go edit in a fork of the jasmine-maven-plugin to invent something for this, but I post here in case I'm missing something.

Comment: It sounds like a interesting problem, how did it finish?

Comment: It didn't. I eventually bailed.